# Where do I get packages via windows?

Tags: windows, package-management, internet, downloads, usability

I need packages, man.  I can't find them.  I can find 'source clones'.  Are those packages?  I'm not connect to the Internet in Linux, so I need to download the packages on my Windows system.  Where do I get the packages?  Where are the ***PACKAGES?!?!?!?!***

Comment: what package you want to install

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Hey guys: I understand there's a duplicate; however, the terminology is useful for search engines.  We should leave this post visible, for reference.

Comment: do not use ALL CAPS.It is considered shouting on Internet.

Comment: do not use all caps.It is considered shouting on Internet.

Answer (score 2):

They are here, strangely enough: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Be certain to get the package matching your version and architecture; either 32- or 64-bit. Find out from the terminal:

```
lsb_release -d
arch
```